# while using session in php during log in when the user is directed to user account page the page is empty

Tags: php, session, mysqli, phpmyadmin

I have a log in page in there i have set some sessions so once after the user is logged in the gets directed to user page ie www.sitename/users/index.php on this page there is profile info and password &email change update etc.. the regular stuff.
The issue i'm encountering is the when the user is logged in after redirecting via php header function the user profile page section is not showing.

This is my php log in code:

```
<?php 
session_start();
include 'include/db-conn.php';
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    $username = $_POST['user_name'];
    $email = $_POST['user_email'];
    $password = $_POST['user_password'];

    $sql = "SELECT * FROM `all_users` WHERE `user_name`='$username' AND `user_email`='$email'";
    $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
    $user = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);

    if ($user['status'] == '0') {
        echo "<script>alert('Your Account needs to be verified first , check your email that you got during signing up!')</script>";
        exit();
        header("Location: index.php");
    }
    if ($user['status'] == '2') {
        echo "<script>alert('Your Account Status is 2!')</script>";
        exit();
        header("Location: index.php");
    }
    if ($user['status'] == '3') {
        echo "<script>alert('Your Account Status is 3!!')</script>";
        exit();
        header("Location: index.php");
    }
    if ($user['status'] == '4') {
        exit();
        header('Location: index.php');
    }

    if ($user['user_name'] == $username && $user['user_email'] == $email && password_verify($password, $user['user_password'])) {
        $_SESSION['id'] = $user['id'];
        $_SESSION['userid'] = $user['user_random_id'];
        $_SESSION['username'] = $user['user_name'];
        $_SESSION['email'] = $user['user_email'];
        $_SESSION['user_role_type'] = $user['user_role_type_name'];
        $_SESSION['main_user_type'] = $user['main_user_group'];
        $_SESSION['sub_user_type'] = $user['sub_user_group'];
        $_SESSION['logged_in'] = true;
        echo '<script>location.href=users/index.php;</script>';
        header("Location: users/index.php");
        //ob_enf_fluch();
    } else {
        echo "<script>alert('Please check your credentials. Your user name, email or password are incorrect')</script>";
        header("Location: index.php");
    }
}
```

?>

And this the session check for user account pages so they only have access when they logged in:

```
<?php 
if (!isset($_SESSION['main_user_group'])) {
    header("Location: index.php");
    exit();
}
```

?>

the is the html code:

```
<div class="panel panel-default">
                <div class="panel-heading">Log In</div>
                <div class="panel-body">
                    <form name="userLogin" action="login-script.php" method="POST" onsubmit="return validateForm()">


                        <!---->
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="user_name">Username</label>
                            <input required="required" placeholder="enter here" type="text" name="user_name" class="form-control">
                        </div>
                        <hr>

                        <!---->
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="user_email">Email</label>
                            <input required="required" placeholder="enter here" type="email" name="user_email" class="form-control">
                        </div>
                        <hr>

                        <!---->
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="user_password">Password</label>
                            <input required="required" placeholder="enter here" type="password" name="user_password" class="form-control">
                        </div>
                </div>
                <div class="panel-footer">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <input placeholder="enter here" type="submit" name="submit" value="submit" class="form-control btn btn-success">
                    </div>
                </div>
                </form>
            </div>
```

And this the user section www.somesite.com/users/index page content:

```
   <?php include '../include/db-conn.php'; ?>
<?php include '../include/header.php'; ?>
<?php include 'session-check.php'; ?>
<!--Section-->
<div class="container-fluid p0 m0 ">
    <ul class="breadcrumb m0 p20">
      <li>Users</li>
      <li class="active">Account</li>
    </ul> 
</div>
<!-- Section-->

<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <br>
            <div class="col-md-3">
                <div class="panel panel-default">
                    <div class="panel-heading">
                        Links
                    </div>
                    <div class="panel-body p0">
                        <?php include 'common-links.php'; ?>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-9">
                <form action="">
                    <div class="col-md-3">
                        <div class="panel panel-default p0">
                            <div class="panel-heading">Image</div>
                            <div class="panel-body p0">
                                <img class="img-responsive" src="https://s3.amazonaws.com/uifaces/faces/twitter/rem/128.jpg" width="100%" height="100%" alt="">
                                <label for="user_image"><input class="form-control" type="file" name="user_image"></label>
                            </div>
                            <div class="panel-footer">
                                <p>User Role:</p>
                                <p>Username:</p>
                                <p>Joined:</p>
                                <p>User ID:</p>
                                <p>Email Verified:</p>
                            </div>
                        </div>                                                             
                    </div>

                    <div class="col-md-9">
                        <div class="panel panel-default p0">
                            <div class="panel-heading">Profile Info</div>
                            <div class="panel-body">
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label for="user_title">Title</label>
                                    <select  class="form-control select" name="user_title" id="">
                                        <option value="non-selected">Non Selected</option>
                                        <option value="Mr">Mr</option>
                                        <option value="Mrs">Mrs</option>
                                        <option value="Miss">Miss</option>
                                        <option value="oters">Others</option>
                                    </select>
                                </div>
                                <hr>

                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label for="user_gender">Gender</label>
                                    <select  class="form-control select" name="user_gender" id="">
                                        <option value="non-selected">Non Selected</option>
                                        <option value="Female">Female</option>
                                        <option value="Male">Male</option>
                                        <option value="Tansgender">Tansgender</option>
                                        <option value="Bi-Sexual">Bi-Sexual</option>
                                        <option value="oters">Others</option>
                                    </select>
                                </div>
                                <hr>

                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label for="user_first_name">First Name</label>
                                    <input required class="form-control" type="text" name="user_first_name" placeholder="enter here">
                                </div>
                                <hr>

                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label for="user_middle_name">Middle Name</label>
                                    <input required class="form-control" type="text" name="user_middle_name" placeholder="enter here">
                                </div>
                                <hr>

                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label for="user_last_name">Lastname</label>
                                    <input required class="form-control" type="text" name="user_last_name" placeholder="enter here">
                                </div>
                                <hr>

                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label for="user_dob">D.O.B</label>
                                    <input required class="form-control"  type="date" name="user_dob" placeholder="enter here">
                                </div>
                                <hr class="">

                                <textarea class="tinymce form-control"  cols="30" rows="10" name="about_user" placeholder="Write something about yourself!"></textarea>
                                <hr>

                                <h3>Address</h3>
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label for="user_address_number">Address No</label>
                                    <input required class="form-control" type="text" name="user_address_number" placeholder="enter here">
                                </div>
                                <hr>

                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label for="user_address_street">Address Street</label>
                                    <input required class="form-control" type="text" name="user_address_street" placeholder="enter here">
                                </div>
                                <hr>

                                <!--get country from the db-->
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label for="user_address_country">Country(select)</label>
                                    <select class="form-control select" name="user_address_country" id="">
                                        <option value="non-selected">None Selected</option>
                                        <option value="GB">United Kingdom</option>
                                    </select>
                                </div>
                                <hr>

                                <!--get state from the db-->
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label for="user_address_state">State / County /Province / Region (select)</label>
                                    <select class="form-control select" name="user_address_state" id="">
                                        <option value="non-selected">None Selected</option>
                                        <option value="GB">United Kingdom</option>
                                    </select>
                                </div>
                                <hr>

                                <!--get city from the db-->
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label for="user_address_city">City (select)</label>
                                    <select class="form-control select" name="user_address_city" id="">
                                        <option value="non-selected">None Selected</option>
                                        <option value="GB">United Kingdom</option>
                                    </select>
                                </div>
                                <hr>

                                <!--get town from the db-->
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label for="user_address_town">Town  (select)</label>
                                    <select class="form-control select" name="user_address_town" id="">
                                        <option value="non-selected">None Selected</option>
                                        <option value="GB">United Kingdom</option>
                                    </select>
                                </div>
                                <hr>

                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label for="user_address_post_code_zip">Post / Zip Code </label>
                                    <input required class="form-control" type="text" name="user_address_post_code_zip" placeholder="enter here">
                                </div>
                                <hr>

                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label for="user_phone_number">Phone Number</label>
                                    <input class="form-control" type="tel" name="user_phone_number" placeholder="enter here">
                                </div>
                                <hr>

                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label for="user_mobile_number">Mobile Number</label>
                                    <input class="form-control" type="tel" name="user_mobile_number" placeholder="enter here">
                                </div>
                                <hr>

                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label for="user_email">User Email</label>
                                    <input required class="form-control" type="email" name="user_email" placeholder="enter here">
                                </div>
                                <hr>

                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <input class="form-control btn-success" type="submit" name="save" value="Save">
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <br>    
</div>

<?php include '../include/footer.php'; ?>
```

Comment: Your question heading and body don't match. You said the user profile page fails to display. Where is the code that displays said page? The code you have added has nothing to do with what you have described in your "question"

Comment: sure ill the users/index.php code to!

Comment: Hi Akintunde-Rotimi i have added the user section content ...thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try giving the code if this code does not work check your password hash format correct or not.
**Note:** user/index.php must start session "session_start();"

```
<?php 
    session_start();
    include 'include/db-conn.php';
    if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
        $username = $_POST['user_name'];
        $email = $_POST['user_email'];
        $password = md5($_POST['user_password']);
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM `all_users` WHERE `user_name`='$username' AND `user_email`='$email' AND `user_password`='$password'";
        $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
        $user = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
        if(!empty($user)){
            if ($user['status'] == '0') {
                echo "<script>alert('Your Account needs to be verified first , check your email that you got during signing up!')</script>";
                exit;
                header("Location: index.php");
            }elseif($user['status'] == '2') {
                echo "<script>alert('Your Account Status is 2!')</script>";
                exit;
                header("Location: index.php");
            }elseif($user['status'] == '3') {
                echo "<script>alert('Your Account Status is 3!!')</script>";
                exit;
                header("Location: index.php");
            }elseif($user['status'] == '4') {
                exit;
                header('Location: index.php');
            }
            $_SESSION['id'] = $user['id'];
            $_SESSION['userid'] = $user['user_random_id'];
            $_SESSION['username'] = $user['user_name'];
            $_SESSION['email'] = $user['user_email'];
            $_SESSION['user_role_type'] = $user['user_role_type_name'];
            $_SESSION['main_user_group'] = $user['main_user_group'];
            $_SESSION['sub_user_type'] = $user['sub_user_group'];
            $_SESSION['logged_in'] = true;
            header("Location: users/index.php");
        }else {
            echo "<script>alert('Please check your credentials. Your user name, email or password are incorrect')</script>";
            header("Location: index.php");
        }
    }
?>
```

Comment: its not working still now its giving me this error:                                              
This page isn’t working localhost redirected you too many times.
Try clearing your cookies.
ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS         /// The password been working fine cos the user gets directed to their account profile page but nothing appears also the session_start(); is added!

Comment: where is your variable echo on index.php? @ Tahir D

Comment: sorry which variable are referring to ? is it on users/index.php ?

Comment: its  giving me this error now : Warning: session_start(): Cannot start session when headers already sent in C:\xampp\htdocs\login-panel\log-in.php on line 34. this error refering to  the same line where the session_start(): is added in the code you gave!

Answer (score 0):

The reason the html section wasn't displaying was the html was before session_start(); as i was using php include function to render html across the site mainly the header.php.
The issue is resolved  by adding a session_start(); at the start of the header.php which is rendered by the php include function or just make sure session_start(); is above html tag in any given situation.

Kindly correct me if I'm wrong, but it seem to have worked for me!
Thanks